# Multiple variable in a measure returns blank or zero

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have multiple variable (Calculated) in a measure and giving me a blank result.
let say I have 4 variable inside the measure and one of then has a null value or zero.
The formula is to multiply all 4 variable and this is what I applied in my measure to removed the null or blank by adding COALESCE to variable.
The problem with this code , if all of then are null or zero returns 1 and converted to 100.00%

Is there any idea or suggestion to simplify or fix this kind of scenario.

Sample

```
 Measure (Yield %) =
    VAR _p1 = DIVIDE(table_measure[Pass], PY_Measures[Pass_Input], 0)   
    VAR _p2 = DIVIDE(table_measure[Fail], PY_Measures[Fail_Input ], 0)  
    VAR _p3 =  DIVIDE(table_measure[Good],  PY_Measures[Good_Input], 0)  
    VAR _p4  =  DIVIDE(table_measure[Bad], PY_Measures[Bad_Input], 0) 
 RETURN
    (COALESCE(_p1,1) * COALESCE(_p2,1) * COALESCE(_p3,1) * COALESCE(_p4,1))
```

Data
var---output
p1----1
p2----96.63%
p3----93.39%
p4----92.81%

Desired result
Measure (Yield%)    83.75%

PY_Measures is a folder that store all the measures I created.
Here is the sample of measure I created for where the _P1 variable comes from(output)

```
Pass_Input = Calculate(PY_Measures(touched), filter(PY,(PY[Category]='WB') && (PY[type='ALL')))
  

 Pass = Calculate(PY_Measures(touched), filter(PY,(PY[Category]='WB') && (PY[type_category='Pass')))
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: What will be PY_Measures looks like?

Comment: Pass_Input = Calculate(PY_Measures(touched), filter(PY,(PY[Category]='WB') && (PY[type='ALL')))
  

Pass = Calculate(PY_Measures(touched), filter(PY,(PY[Category]='WB') && (PY[type_category='Pass')))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the sum of your variables is larger than zero:

```
Stuff =
VAR _p1 = DIVIDE ( table_measure[Pass], PY_Measures[Pass_Input], 0 )
VAR _p2 = DIVIDE ( table_measure[Fail], PY_Measures[Fail_Input ], 0 )
VAR _p3 = DIVIDE ( table_measure[Good], PY_Measures[Good_Input], 0 )
VAR _p4 = DIVIDE ( table_measure[Bad], PY_Measures[Bad_Input], 0 )
RETURN
    IF (
        ( _p1 + _p2 + _p3 + _p4 ) > 0,
        COALESCE ( _p1, 1 ) * COALESCE ( _p2, 1 ) * COALESCE ( _p3, 1 ) * COALESCE ( _p4, 1 ),
        0
    )
```